# Can cell phones send message in the elevator?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, everyday-life, conductors, antennas, microwaves

From Gauss's theorem, a closed, hollow conductor shields its interior from fields due to charges outside, but does not shield its exterior from the fields due to charges placed inside it. So my opinion is in the elevator, i.e. a Faraday cage, cell phones cannot receive message from outside correspondent but can send message to outside correspondent. Is that true?

Comment: relevant  https://www.classlifestyle.com/news/40166/pse-nuk-duhet-te-flisni-kurre-ne-telefon-kur-ndodheni-ne-ashensor/eng/

Comment: Consider your microwave oven.

Comment: If your cell phone can create a nonzero net charge while being in this closed hollow conductor then your reasoning might be true. Can it?

Comment: Why not do this experiment?